# Missing Hotfixes on SharePoint BackEnd Server

Tags: 2013, health-analyzer, web-app-server

We have a 4 Server farm. 2 Web-Front-End-Server and 2 Backend-Server. A week ago, the health analyzer said, that one of the back-end Servers is missing updates. The missing updates are:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880558
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2878240

The Problem is, that the web app Server is a different Server and not one of the 4 SharePoint Servers. All other SharePoint Servers had the Hotfixes and ServicePacks installed.

I downloaded the packages and would like to install it on the SharePoint Server but there was an error:

> Error executing the recognition and the Server don't start to install the update...

Anybody have an idea why one of the Servers aare missing updates and the others Servers are ok? All were updated at the same time with the same updates and last week the health analyzer didn't say, that there are missing updates.

I use PowerShell with

- `GetSPProduct - Local`, but the error is the same...

Comment: what's the health analyzer warning details ? is it Missing server side dependencies  ?

Comment: So you has issue on the Office Web App Server? is it part of Sharepoint farm or separate farm?

Comment: The web app server are in another department. You mean, that the web app server had issues so that one of my SharePoint Servers says that they had missing updates? But the second missing updates issnt a web app Problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch of  windows updates or SharePoint updates (Cumulative Update,Service Pack …etc) in one or more servers in the farm,

**You should make sure that**

- all required products must be installed on all SharePoint servers in the farm,
- all SharePoint products should have the same patching and upgrade level across the farm.

Also, You should be aware of the Patching/Updating  SharePoint is performed through a two-step process :

- Install the package update and make sure it's installed on all SharePoint server.
- Run the SharePoint Configuration wizard.

  PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures

Comment: I am also here if you need more clarification

Comment: Cannot use psconfig if one Server had missing updates?

Comment: you should first match the updates for all SharePoint servers

Comment: Are you know how to get the latest patch level on the server?

Comment: I cannot do it. I use Windows update and the Server didnt find the missing updates. If i download the two updates and install it on the Server the error i write up cames... so what should i do?

Comment: should you calrify to me this point "the web app Server is a different Server and not one of the 4 SharePoint Servers. " to can help you

Comment: We had 4 SharePoint Servers and one web app server...

Comment: web app server has already joined to your farm ? Are 4 SharePoint Servers with application server role? Is web app server that not updated ?

Comment: I dont the web app server in the server overview.... that mean, that the web apps are on the two back end Servers? Since last week one of them had missing updates...

Comment: No two are application server role and two are web front end

Comment: How can i update the missing updates on one back end Server, if Windows update is not finding any updates and the manuell downloaded update packages cannot be installed with the error "Error executing the recognition"

Comment: Now i see, the second hotfix KB2878240 is installed on the second back end Server, but in SharePoint Managed Path Status they say, that the hotfix is missing. Windows says, that it was installed in july 2014. Anybody know how to fix this missmatch?

Comment: Is this a production environment ? also should you go to the application server that host the central administration > system setting > server in farm and check if there's server with need to upgrade status

Comment: If you need , Today, after work  I can connect with you remotely to check it , I got the same issue before I hope to can help you.

Comment: Yes, its a production enviroment. Under Server in the farm he says, that a Installation is required. I check the missing hotfix on the Windows System and the hotfix is installed, but SharePoint think the hotfix is missing. If i get powershell with the command "(Get-SpServer $env:ComputerName).NeedsUpgrade" he says False on all Servers...